# How to retrieve non key columns on inserting the record into the table?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I know I can use the following query to get the primary key of the record inserted into the table.

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO TABLE(ID, col1, col2)"
            + "VALUES(TABLE.TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :param1, :param2)",
            parameters, keyHolder, new String[]{"KEY_COLUMN_NAME"});
```

But can I use the same thing to get the non-key columns as well?

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO TABLE(ID, col1, col2)"
            + "VALUES(TABLE.TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :param1, :param2)",
            parameters, keyHolder, new String[]{"KEY_COLUMN_NAME","NON_KEY_COLUMN_NAME});
```

In fact I can if the NON_KEY_COLUMN_NAME column is of type varchar. If it is a date it is throwing an exception that it was an unknown column type. Basically I wanted to get the primary key of the inserted record and the date it got inserted. How do I achieve this?

Comment: since you are inserting "now" you already know the insertion "date" which is new Date(). Why would you want to get it from db?

Comment: We have database trigger that populates the date. And want to do it that way to be consistent with rest of the system.